# QMultimediaWidgets unable to load on Windows

Tags: windows, qt, video, dll

I want to use the QVideoWidget class from QMultimediaWidgets. I'm using Qt 5.15.2 on windows 10 with msvc2019_64. My build succeed, but when I try to run my application I got an error message `Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135)` and nothing else. Every .dll I need are in the right folder (Qt5Core.dll, Qt5Gui, Qt5Multimedia, Qt5Widgets, Qt5Network.dll, Qt5Test.dll, Qt5MultimediaWidgets.dll). Every library I use are found by cmake (TensorRT, Cuda, OpenCV, Juce, asio (audio stream IO), pylon (Basler SDK) and NIDAQmx (x64)).

I tested the program without QMultimediaWidgets and it runs absolutely fine.

I tried on Ubuntu 18.04, everything fine even with my components using QMultimediaWidgets.

I created a dummy project that only purpose is to display a video in QVideoWidget and nothing else, same error.

I tried on another computer, same error.

I tried to uninstall and reinstall Qt5.15.2, same error.

I'm running out of options to make this work, any ideas?

Sincerely yours,

```cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QVideoWidget>
#include <QMediaPlayer>
#include <QMediaPlaylist>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    auto player = new QMediaPlayer;
    auto playlist = new QMediaPlaylist;
    auto videoWidget = new QVideoWidget;
    videoWidget->show();
    playlist->addMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("C:/film_dlc_02.wmv"));
    playlist->addMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("C:/film_dlc_01.wmv"));
    player->setVideoOutput(videoWidget);
    player->setPlaylist(playlist);
    playlist->setCurrentIndex(0);
    player->play();
    return a.exec();
}
```

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)
project(MinimalExampleQVideoWidget)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:/Qt/5.15.2/msvc2019_64")
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

set(QT_VERSION 5)
set(REQUIRED_LIBS Core Gui Widgets Multimedia MultimediaWidgets)
set(REQUIRED_LIBS_QUALIFIED Qt5::Core Qt5::Gui Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Multimedia Qt5::MultimediaWidgets)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

if (NOT CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH)
    message(WARNING "CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH is not defined, you may need to set it "
            "(-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=\"path/to/Qt/lib/cmake\" or -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/include/{host}/qt{version}/ on Ubuntu)")
endif ()

find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION} COMPONENTS ${REQUIRED_LIBS} REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${REQUIRED_LIBS_QUALIFIED})
if (WIN32)
    set(DEBUG_SUFFIX)
    if (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES "Debug")
        set(DEBUG_SUFFIX "d")
    endif ()
    set(QT_INSTALL_PATH "${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}")
    if (NOT EXISTS "${QT_INSTALL_PATH}/bin")
        set(QT_INSTALL_PATH "${QT_INSTALL_PATH}/..")
        if (NOT EXISTS "${QT_INSTALL_PATH}/bin")
            set(QT_INSTALL_PATH "${QT_INSTALL_PATH}/..")
        endif ()
    endif ()
    if (EXISTS "${QT_INSTALL_PATH}/plugins/platforms/qwindows${DEBUG_SUFFIX}.dll")
        add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD
                COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory
                "$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME}>/plugins/platforms/")
        add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD
                COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy
                "${QT_INSTALL_PATH}/plugins/platforms/qwindows${DEBUG_SUFFIX}.dll"
                "$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME}>/plugins/platforms/")
    endif ()
    foreach (QT_LIB ${REQUIRED_LIBS})
        add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD
                COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy
                "${QT_INSTALL_PATH}/bin/Qt${QT_VERSION}${QT_LIB}${DEBUG_SUFFIX}.dll"
                "$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME}>")
    endforeach (QT_LIB)
endif ()
```

EDIT: I tried the minimum example in qmake (instead of cmake), it works.

EDIT 2: I added in `CMakeLists.txt`: Qt5::Network, the error message disapeared, the minimal example program is launching, it outputs `defaultServiceProvider::requestService(): no service found for - "org.qt-project.qt.mediaplayer"`.

F

Comment: _Every .dll I need are in the right folder_ How do you know that?

Comment: I assume that the Qt's .dll are in the folder where my executable is, I asked for libs: Core, Gui, Widget, Multimedia, MultimediaWidgets, Test, Network. And I have all of it as .dll. If Debug mode is selected: +d on my .dll name, no suffix for my release build.

Comment: `return QApplication::exec();` should be `return a.exec();`

Comment: Still not reproducible. `#include <QApplication>
#include <QVideoWidget>
#include <QMediaPlayer>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 QApplication a(argc, argv);
 auto *player = new QMediaPlayer;
 auto *videoWidget = new QVideoWidget;

 videoWidget->show();
 videoWidget->resize(800, 600);

 player->setMedia(QUrl("C:/test.avi"));
 player->setVideoOutput(videoWidget);
 player->play();

 return a.exec();
}` works just fine.

Comment: Maybe my Qt is looking for Gstreamer / ffmpeg / DirectShow and not able to find it?

Comment: Is `QUrl("C:/Users/path/random/video.mp4")` valid?  Are you sure it doesn't try to interpret `C` as the scheme?  I'm just guessing but you might want to try something like `QUrl("file://C:/Users/path/random/video.mp4")` instead.

Comment: ...or even [`QUrl::fromLocalFile("C:/Users/path/random/video.mp4")`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qurl.html#fromLocalFile).

Comment: even `->setCurrentIndex(1)` as I have only one file in media...

Comment: So shouldn't it be `playlist->setCurrentIndex(0)`?  I'm guessing the indexing is zero based.

Comment: Absolutely! I copy-pasted something from Qt documentation and put it there without paying attention.

Comment: It's definitively working when I build the example in qmake, but not at all in CMake. I'll try to find out what's wrong with CMake.

Answer (score 0):

Same as always: make a debug build, install Qt along with Debug Symbols (there's an option for that in the installer), and run it under the debugger.

> I created a dummy project that only purpose is to display a video in QVideoWidget and nothing else, same error.

I am really surprised: if your program crashes, isn't your first idea to run it in the debugger?

> I'm running out of options to make this work, any ideas?

Uh, but, you have not tried anything yet really... :) Debugging is the only step that will tell you where the problem happens, and hopefully it'll be obvious how to fix it then.

The crash may happen in Qt code, but that's why you'll install both the debug symbols and the source (via the installer) so that you can actually debug inside Qt code, and get ideas for a workaround etc.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I can't even start the debugger. It outputs:```cmake-build-debug\BingoBike.exe

process launch failed: unknown error

Process finished with exit code 0```.